# jqGrid tableToGrid formatting a column for phone numbers

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-asp.net

I need to figure out a way to get certain column's of my jquery's tableToGrid call to format a couple of my cells.  I know that you can place a formater in the colModel and that will format that column for you.  I was wondering if there was a standard phone number formatter, or will I be forced to write one?  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure how you want to format you phonenumber, but here's some code I used for a project. If you uncomment the right lines you can switch between `(xxx)xxx-xxxx` and `xxx-xxx-xxxx`

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'phonenumber', index: 'phonenumber', width: 60, align: "center", formatter: formatPhoneNumber}
]

// converts number to (xxx)xxx-xxxx or xxx-xxx-xxxx
function formatPhoneNumber(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var re = /\D/;
    // test for this format: (xxx)xxx-xxxx
    var re2 = /^\({1}\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}/;
    // test for this format: xxx-xxx-xxxx
    //var re2 = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/;
    var num = cellvalue;
    if (num === null){
        num = "";
    }
    var newNum = num;
    if (num != "" && re2.test(num) != true) {
        if (num != "") {
            while (re.test(num)) {
                num = num.replace(re, "");
            }
        }
        if (num.length == 10) {
            // for format (xxx)xxx-xxxx
            newNum = '(' + num.substring(0, 3) + ')' + num.substring(3, 6) + '-' + num.substring(6, 10);
            // for format xxx-xxx-xxxx
            // newNum = num.substring(0,3) + '-' + num.substring(3,6) + '-' + num.substring(6,10);
        }
    }
    return newNum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**I think this is best way...**

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'phonenumber', index: 'phonenumber', width: 60, align: "center", formatter: formatPhoneNumber}
]
function formatPhoneNumber(cellvalue, options, rowObject) { 
     var re = new RegExp("([0-9])([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3,6})", "g");
     cellvalue=cellvalue.replace(re, "+$1($2)-$3-$4");  
    return cellvalue;
}
```

Comment: That worked well for me for international phone numbers.  For U.S. only, I simplified it back to

function formatPhoneNumber(cellvalue, options, rowObject) { 
     var re = new RegExp("([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4,6})", "g");
     cellvalue=cellvalue.replace(re, "($1) $2-$3");  
    return cellvalue;
}